# Deleting own question with low views

Tags: discussion

Lately, I posted several questions on stackoverflow concerning some very specific matter (JBossESB and other SOA-related issues). It took me quite a lot of time to figure them out but eventually, I found the answers myself.

The topic I am working on is apparently not very ordinary on SO and I didnt get any answer from anybody (it has very low views, too). So my question is: Is it better to delete these posts or post my answers, even if it will be hardly viewed by anyone?

Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Why *wouldn't* you post an answer?!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is it better to delete these posts or post my answers, even if it will be hardly viewed by anyone?

Don't delete them.

Definitely post answers - though you may think an answer will not be helpful, you can't tell the future and any answer you post may very well be a help to future readers.

Answer (score 7):

## Post your answers!

As long as your questions are within the guidelines of the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) you shouldn't delete them. If *you've* had this problem it's likely that *someone* will benefit by your answer.

Answer (score 2):

To answer this in a nutshell: enter any kind of common programming question in Google, and chances are the first 2 to 3 hits are on Stack Overflow. Not so much for rarer topics such as JBossESB though. So, why not be the one to change that?

One of SO's most important functions, with its solution-oriented approach (SOA! ;) is to become the definitive knowledge base of all problems a programmer can run into, and conveniently mark a working solution with a big green checkmark that says **"this works if you run into this problem"**.

So grab your chance, become the number 1 JBossESB knowledge resource on the internet, with the help of SO's PageRank, and post your answers and mark them to be correct!